# Hijack click event with JavaScript whilst page loads

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom, interaction

When creating any site that uses JavaScript I usually hook into anchors for my click listeners. This is so that if JavaScript isn't supported or is turned off the site will still work for users. I put the majority of my script code at the end of the document near `</body>` so that the content is loaded first. The only exceptions being things like modernizr, google tracking code, etc.

However in doing this it means there is a time period in which anchors are present on the page in which time the user can interact with them before the JavaScript has loaded and attached event listeners.

I thought about adding some stubs to all the anchors but I can't figure out a way to make it work, considering that the anchors haven't been put on the page yet if my stub script is above the `<body>` element. I assume it's possible as the old jQuery `live()` function did something similar (I'm aware that's now deprecated 1.7 and removed 1.9).

The idea would be I create a do nothing stub for all interaction points. Point the interaction points to it whilst the page loads. Once everything has loaded remove the stubs and use the fully defined listeners.

Has anyone done this before... or got a better solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I assume it's possible as the old jQuery live() function did something similar (I'm aware that's now deprecated 1.7 and removed 1.9).

I think that's pretty close. It's been replaced with `.on('EVENT', 'SELECTOR', FUNCTION)`.

You could use something like:

```
$(document).on('click', 'a', false); // disable all clicks
```

Then, once it's fully loaded, take the handler off:

```
$(document).off('click', 'a', false);
```

Comment: Hmm... I should have mentioned that jQuery is one of the scripts I load after the content too. I'll give this a try though to see whether it works.

Comment: See more about [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) on the jQuery docs.

Comment: Then you should load jQuery at the beginning for this to work.

Comment: Well yes, obviously. There must be a native equivalent though which isn't as weighty as loading jQuery.

Comment: Theoretically, you could add a click listener to `window`, and check if the actual target was an anchor, but what if you have children in your anchors? Then it gets more complex. You're already loading jQuery, so what's wrong with moving it up? Loading scripts shouldn't interfere with loading the rest of the content.

Comment: Fair points. The `$.on()` function does the trick too. Cheers.